# Apache Spark AttributeError: FileFormat, ValueError: 'FileFormat' is not in list Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

Whenever I execute the following function I get the error:

AttributeError: FileFormat, ValueError: 'FileFormat'

```
def getAncestorPath(connectionInst: conn.connect, log: logs.Logging,  processId, entityStageId = "-1"):
  log.writeToLogs(processId,logs.LogType.Info, logs.EventType.GetAncestorPath, logs.LogMessage.GetAncestorPath)
  pathQuery = f"SELECT * FROM Config.GetAncestorSlicePath WHERE (ProcessID = {processId}) OR (ProcessID IS NULL AND EntityStageID = {entityStageId})"
  
  AncestorPath = ""
  dfConfig = ""
  
  entityPath = connectionInst.readFromDb(processId,pathQuery)
  
  ancestorPathToList = entityPath.limit(1).rdd.collect()
  
  if len(ancestorPathToList) is 0:
    log.writeToLogs(processId,logs.LogType.Error, logs.EventType.NoAncestorPath, logs.LogMessage.NoAncestorPath, errorType = logs.ErrorType.NoAncestorPath)
    log.writeToLogs(processId,logs.LogType.Error, logs.EventType.FailGetAncestorPath, logs.LogMessage.FailGetAncestorPath, errorType = logs.ErrorType.FailGetAncestorPath)
    raise ValueError(logs.LogMessage.NoAncestorPath.value)
  
  for row in ancestorPathToList:
    AncestorPath = f"/mnt/lake/{row.LakePath}"
    dfConfig = row.Config
  
  log.writeToLogs(processId,logs.LogType.Info, logs.EventType.SuccessGetAncestorPath, logs.LogMessage.SuccessGetAncestorPath)
  return {"ancestorPath":AncestorPath,"dfConfig":dfConfig}
```

To execute the function I run the following code:

```
Ancestor = getAncestorPath(processId, entityStageId)
dataPath = Ancestor["ancestorPath"]
fileFormat = Ancestor["fileFormat"]
```

The variables I use for the function are as follows:

processId = 107
entityStageId = 30

The full error stack is as follows:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py in __getattr__(self, item)
   1570             # but this will not be used in normal cases
-> 1571             idx = self.__fields__.index(item)
   1572             return self[idx]

ValueError: 'FileFormat' is not in list

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-2987786675547475> in <module>
      1 #The Ancestor Path builds a data lake path for our data to be processed, and pulls any processing configuration from the metadata database
----> 2 Ancestor = ancestor.getAncestorPath(conn,log,processId, entityStageId)
      3 dataPath = Ancestor["ancestorPath"]
      4 fileFormat = Ancestor["fileFormat"]
      5 

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hydr8/cln/ancestor.py in getAncestorPath(connectionInst, log, processId, entityStageId)
     30     AncestorPath = f"/mnt/lake/{row.LakePath}"
     31     dfConfig = row.Config
---> 32     FileFormat = row.FileFormat
     33 
     34   log.writeToLogs(processId,logs.LogType.Info, logs.EventType.SuccessGetAncestorPath, logs.LogMessage.SuccessGetAncestorPath)

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py in __getattr__(self, item)
   1574             raise AttributeError(item)
   1575         except ValueError:
-> 1576             raise AttributeError(item)
   1577 
   1578     def __setattr__(self, key, value):

AttributeError: FileFormat
```

I think the problem may be to do with the following:

```
getAncestorPath(connectionInst: conn.connect, log: logs.Logging,  processId, entityStageId = "-1"):
```

But I'm not sure.

Any thoughts

Comment: Seems like you don't have FileFormat column in the collect output. Can you check whether you have `FileFormat` column present in `ancestorPathToList`.

- Another point to note, the function `getAncestorPath` in your question and `/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hydr8/cln/ancestor.py in getAncestorPath` seems not matching, the one in stacktrace has `row.FileFormat` are these both functions are same?

Comment: Hi @nalanagula, thanks for getting in touch, unfortunately I don't entirely understand what you mean when you mentione checking if FileFormat is present?
Also, how did you discover the functions row.FileFormat differ?

Comment: @nalanagula, I think you might be on to something. You appear to correct that there isn't a column called FileFormat. However, I don't see anywhere in my code that I'm calling for the column FileFormat

Comment: @nalanagula, you're a star - the problem was a missing FileFormat